# Easiest way to make multiple pointers point to the same location when only handling 2 at a time

Tags: c++, pointers

I was wondering if there is a way in C++ to have multiple pointers equal to each other when you can only access a pair at a time.

```cpp
void point_to_same_location(int*& pt1, int*& pt2) {
   // fucntion goes here
}
```

```cpp
int* pt1;
int* pt2;
int* pt3;

point_to_same_loaction(pt1, pt2);
point_to_same_location(pt2, pt3);
```

What can I put in the function body so that `pt1 = pt2 = pt3`?

edit: I'm looking for a way that avoids using pt2 = pt1

Comment: Is it required to use `int*` or is `void*` allowed?

Comment: `void point_to_same_location(int* const & pt1, int*& pt2)
{
 pt2= pt1;
}
`

https://ideone.com/xM8zj8

Comment: How could you do it with void* @BenVoigt?

Comment: Thank you @Mirko, but I forgot to mention that I'm strictly wanting to avoid pt2 = pt1. is there any other way?

Comment: @AbdelsalamElTamawy: Make linked lists, treat the last item in the list (the one that points to NULL) as the identity of the whole list.  Then join lists together (link the head to any item in the other list) to make them equal.

Comment: Does `pt2+= pt1 - pt2;` work for you?

Comment: `void point_to_same_location(int* const & pt1, int*& pt2) { pt1 = nullptr; pt2 = nullptr; }` This doesn't contain `pt2 = pt1`, and does meet the postcondition `pt1 == pt2 == pt3`

Comment: You want to assign a value to a variable but you don't want to make an assignment? What?

Comment: Do you mean `pt1 == pt2 && pt2 == pt3` or do you really mean `pt1 = pt2 = pt3`? I think the latter isn't possible. You can't set `pt1` to the value of `pt3` in the given order.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid `pt1 = pt2;` you can use `std::memcpy` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void point_to_same_location(int*& pt1, int*& pt2) {
    std::memcpy(&pt1, &pt2, sizeof(pt1));
}

int main() {
    int* pt1;
    int* pt2;
    int* pt3;
    int a = 10;
    pt2 = &a;

    std::cout << pt2 << std::endl;
    point_to_same_location(pt1, pt2);
    std::cout << pt1 << std::endl;
    point_to_same_location(pt3, pt2);
    std::cout << pt3 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is very strange, but anyway.

Just note that you should always initialize your pointers to `nullptr` when you create them. It is a lot safer than letting them pointing to somewhere in the memory. And it could allow you to check if a pointer has already been allocated or not.

---

If you want to have two pointers pointing at the same location, then they **must be equal**. So you cannot avoid the affectation `ptr1 = ptr2;` if they aren't.

A way to do this could be:

```
bool point_to_the_same_location(int *& ptr1, int *& ptr2)
{
    if(ptr1 != ptr2)
    {
        if(ptr1 == nullptr) // try to affect ptr2 to ptr1
        {
            ptr1 = ptr2;
            return true; // success
        }
        if(ptr2 == nullptr) // try to affect ptr1 to ptr2
        {
            ptr2 = ptr1;
            return true; //success
        }

        // At this point both ptr1 and ptr2 != nullptr
        return false; // Both ptr1 and ptr2 are already pointing a different value, you need to release one of them.
    }
    else
        return true; // ptr1 already equals ptr2
}
```

As you can see, if both `ptr1` and `ptr2` are already pointing different values, you cannot make them pointing the same location. If you do it, you will lose the previous value of the one that will be changed and you will create a memory leak.
To avoid it, you could say that you will delete the pointer before affecting a new value, but how to know if you have to use `delete` or `delete []` ? In fact, from the inside of the function, you cannot know if the pointer is pointing a single value or the first element of an array. So you cannot make two pointers point to the same location from inside a function if they are both already pointing somewhere.

---

Another thing, using `std::shared_ptr` could be a much better way than using raw pointers for what you want to do.

I hope it can help you.